# Google Photos - Stop asking to allow edits?

Tags: google-photos

I just got a new phone, I upgraded to a Samsung Galaxy S20 Plus from an LG G8X, and whenever I edit a photo using Google Photos, it always asks me to ALLOW the edit. The Google Photos app never did this on my old LG G8X, so how can I get my new S20 Plus to do the same thing, always allowing my edits without being asked?

I have a pic here illustrating what I'm asking about:
[image: Stop asking to ALLOW edits]

It's not really a problem, more of a minor annoyance that I can live with if there's no solution. Still, If anybody knows how I can set Google Photos to always allow my edits I'd really like to know.

I hope you and your family are all staying safe and healthy! Thanks so much. And Happy Holidays!